# javascript get index of a value in the dropdownlist

Tags: javascript

I am passing a value to the dropdownlist, how to get the index of the value of the dropdownlist and set it using javascript?

```
 document.getElementById("ddlColors").selectedIndex = ?
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you wish to do here? Your Javascript looks OK for setting the index if ddlColors is a <select> element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A loop is the only way, really:

```
var options = document.getElementById('ddlColors').options;

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if(options[i].value === someValue) {
        options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/mUuGh/)

Answer (score 2):

I think I misunderstood your question cause if I didn't the answer is too pretty forward: use the value
http://jsbin.com/urezor/2/edit

Comment: I thought there was a reason one shouldn't do that, but apparently not! :D